# Speed up a people detection program, written using OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, opencv3.0, object-detection

I use OpenCV 3.0.0 and Visual Studio 2012. I've found this program to detect people and count them and determine direction of their motion. But it's very slow. Do you have any idea how to speed it up?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/John/Downloads/Video/Cam.avi");              
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 100);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 110);    
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    return -1;

    Mat img;
    HOGDescriptor hog;
    hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

    namedWindow("video capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while (true)
    {
        cap >> img;
        if (!img.data)
        continue;

        vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
        hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);

        size_t i, j;
        for (i=0; i<found.size(); i++)
        {
            Rect r = found[i];
            for (j=0; j<found.size(); j++)
            if (j!=i && (r & found[j])==r)
            break;
            if (j==found.size())
            found_filtered.push_back(r);
        }
        for (i=0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
        {
            Rect r = found_filtered[i];
            r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
            r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
            r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.06);
            r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.9);
            rectangle(img, r.tl(), r.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2);
        }
        imshow("video capture", img);
        if (waitKey(33) >= 0)
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use smaller images, use gpu, reduce maximum object size, reduce detection area

Comment: Also, define slow and fast in your case

Comment: This works quite fast for me... Did you run it in _release_?

Comment: no, in debug.is it because of video high quality?

Answer (score 1):

if there is an cuda gpu try gpu version of same code

according to this

http://opencv.org/platforms/cuda.html

[image: http://opencv.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/perf.png]

8x times faster for pedesterian detection

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/hog.cpp

Comment: And just so it's clear CUDA is a graphics card API written by the folks at Nvidia. You can make OpenCV run much faster if you have the right hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Resize the frame using
`cv2.resize()`
function to keep frame width at most 300 pixels and then use scaling factor of 1.08 or so inside 
`detectMultiscale()`
 function, and then find the detection speed. It should definitely increase. However, the detection at some points may get less accurate.

Answer (score 0):

First, I replace

```
        Rect r = found_filtered[i];
        r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
        r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
        r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.06);
        r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.9);
        rectangle(img, r.tl(), r.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2);
```

with this code:

```
rectangle(img, Point(found_filtered[i].x ,found_filtered[i].y),   Point(found_filtered[i].x  + found_filtered[i].width, found_filtered[i].y + found_filtered[i].height ),Scalar(255,0,0),2);
```

and it works finely as previous.
For reducing image size and detection I add and edit these codes:
add:

```
resize(img,img,Size(),0.25,0.25,1);
```

and edit rectangle as below:

```
rectangle(img, Point(found_filtered[i].x *4,found_filtered[i].y *4),   Point(found_filtered[i].x *4 + found_filtered[i].width* 4, found_filtered[i].y *4 + found_filtered[i].height *4 ),Scalar(255,0,0),2);
```

but not works.

final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/john/Downloads/Video/file.avi");              
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 100);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 110);    
if (!cap.isOpened())
return -1;

Mat img;
HOGDescriptor hog;
hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

namedWindow("video capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while (true)
{
    cap >> img;
    //resize(img,img,Size(),0.25,0.25,1);
    if (!img.data)
    continue;

    vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
    hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);

    size_t i, j;
    for (i=0; i<found.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect r = found[i];
        for (j=0; j<found.size(); j++)
        if (j!=i && (r & found[j])==r)
        break;
        if (j==found.size())
        found_filtered.push_back(r);
    }
    for (i=0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
    {
        rectangle(img, Point(found_filtered[i].x *4,found_filtered[i].y *4)
        ,Point(found_filtered[i].x *4 + found_filtered[i].width*
         4,found_filtered[i].y*4 + found_filtered[i].height *4 )
         ,Scalar(255,0,0),2);

    }
    imshow("video capture", img);
    if (waitKey(33) >= 0)
    break;
}
return 0;
}
```